# Highcharts export customize axis label and fontsize: No effect after migration

Tags: highcharts, export

I've migrated from Highcharts 6.2.0 to latest (8.1.0 ) and found incompatibility since then.
I noticed that this exists since v7.0.0.
I can't handle the fontSize of YAxis and the label text of the xAxis.

[Working scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/2o4853cp/) `v6.2.0`

[Unworking scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/oxp76zk3/) `v7.0.0+`

Basically what I do in this example :

1. yAxis : display font-size as 4px (ugly of course but to be sure we see the difference b/w working and not working)
2. xAxis : change the text be displaying for example only the first 3 characters of the label. In my real scenario I have a graphic showing flaticons as label and flaticons+text in table (graphic data are based on table to be generated) and so in the export I'd like to see only the text as I got issue with html flaticons to be rendered in the reporting.

Based on highchart's doc, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong....unless doc hasn't been updated and this functionality (to customize our axis) is not gone.

I'm using Chrome/FF and no highchart export server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing it.

It seems like a regression. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel.

Please follow this thread here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13492

If you need a temporary workaround - ask in the comment under the above link. The core developers should respond to you soon after.

---

EDIT

As a temporary workaround enable these options in the load callback and trigger the axes updates.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cprbz1ym/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
      load() {
        if (this.renderer.forExport) {
          this.yAxis[0].update({
            labels: {
              style: {
                fontSize: '4px'
              }
            },
            title: {
              style: {
                fontSize: '4px'
              }
            }
          });
          this.xAxis[0].update({
            labels: {
              style: {
                fontSize: '4px'
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return this.value.substring(0, 2);
              }
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply and links (workaround + issue thread). I've implemented for now the workaround to let me be using v8.1.0.